# how to delete NDB entity using ID?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

based on this docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#deleting_entities 
well, im still not sure why i cannot do the delete on NDB:

```
def get(self):
  id = self.request.get("delete")
  ndb.Key('category', id).delete()
```

yeah i know how to select using id

```
ndb.Key('category', id).get()
```

but its still not working...

```
key = ndb.Key('category', id).get()
key.delete()
```

this one also not working:

```
category.key.delete()
```

something wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
ndb.Key(category, int(id)).delete()
```

You need to convert the id to integer in order to build a numeric (id) key instead of a name key.

Comment: Just curious, doesn't ndb allow us to have string ids? Is not related to the question perhaps, and this already solved his problem.

Comment: @0xc0de of course, if you want to control the id you need to pass a string