# Delete entity from Datastore by ID/ancestry

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have tried to delete an entity from the GAE datastore for hours now and it doesn't work as it should. I pretty much did the same thing as [how to delete NDB entity using ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948901/how-to-delete-ndb-entity-using-id), however I'm sure the problem is with the ancestor relationship.

This is the relevant piece of code:

```
try:
 ndb.Key('NewsBase', int(self.request.get('delid'))).delete()
```

When I print out the `ndb.Key (self.request.out.write...)` I get something like `Key('NewsBase', 8008)`, which is the correct ID (checked in datastore). In the dashboard I also get the "Decoded entity key", which is

```
NewsBase: name=mynews > NewsBase: id=8001
```

I am a little confused on how to include the ancestor information but as far as I can tell from here [Using Key in NDB to retrieve an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834797/using-key-in-ndb-to-retrieve-an-entity) I don't need it at all, or do I?

**EDIT: How I create keys**

```
def news_key(base_name='mynews'):
    return ndb.Key('NewsBase', base_name)

    t = NewsBase(parent=news_key('mynews'))
    t.user = user
    t.put()
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a structure where a `NewsBase` entity will be the parents to more `NewsBase` entities? Are you sure you did not mean to do `t = NewsBase(key=news_key('finagnews'))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the full key, including the ancestor if there is one. That's because the child ID by itself is not necessarily unique: only the full path is, so you need it to identify the particular entity.

In your case, you probably just want `nb.Key('NewsBase', 'mynews', 'NewsBase', 8001)`.

(I suspect however that you are doing something strange to create your keys in the first place: it's unusual to have an ancestor, with a name key, of the same type as the numeric ID of the child.)

Comment: It still doesn't delete it - I created the keys as described in the Getting Started guide, see edit above. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: That's clearly not the full code for your key creation, otherwise everything would be called `mynews`. How are you calling that code? Also, when you say "it doesn't delete it", what *actually* happens? Do you get an error? If so, what?

Comment: No error at all, I suppose it doesn't find anything and thus just skips it. Included the function call. Thanks Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `urlsafe` version of the key instead of the ID:

Output the key as:

`key.urlsafe()` instead of `key.id()`

and delete it in your request handler as:

`ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('delkey')).delete()`

the `urlsafe` version of the key will contain all necessary ancestor information.

Also, does your `news_key` function know that the key its making exists? You should not store an entity with a parent key for an entity that does not exist.

You're `news_key` should probably be something more like:

```
 def news_key(base_name='mynews'):
    return NewsBase.get_or_insert(id=base_name).key
```

Just as an FYI - Deleting the parent does not delete all children. Also, the way you have it shown here, the Parent to your `NewsBase` entity will be another `NewsBase` entity.

Comment: The good news is: the key.urlsafe actually gives me the key (not a Key('NewsBase', id)). But it still doesn't delete the entity. Any idea how to debug?

Comment: And secondly: Why does the getting started guy do it this way (ndb.Key instead of NewsBase.get_or_insert)?

Comment: The `get_or_insert` will make sure there exists an entity with the ID you provided. Not sure what getting started guide you're using, but I can't imagine it would have led you to do things as you are doing them.